# Unable to execute Sudo npm run dev

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install coreui admin theme for laravel project, when I run `sudo npm run dev` it give me error

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/pkg-dir/index.js:5
const pkgDir = async cwd => {
                     ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
    at Module._compile (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:184:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/import-local/index.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
```

Can you let me know what should I do to over some above error.

Comment: Which version of Node are you using (if you're unsure, run `node -v`)?

Comment: It's a problem in your code. Update NodeJS with `nvm install stable` (installs latest stable version).

Comment: @jonrsharpe 
node -v
v14.15.1
npm -v
6.14.9